# Toggle Divs when clicking anywhere on the document

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have multiple buttons on a page such that clicking on a certain button specifies an ID name of a div to make visible, then clicking anywhere else on the page makes that div invisible? I have encountered solutions for a single button and a single div, but I don't know how to implement this solution for multiple buttons and divs.

I have this code, which works perfectly fine for button A and box A:

HTML:

```
        <div class="buttons-div">
            <div class="buttons" id="showBoxA">A</div>
            <div class="buttons">B</div>
        </div>

        <div id="boxes-div" style="z-index: 7">
            <div class="boxes" id="box-a" style="display: none">
                This is box A
            </div>
            <div class="boxes" id="box-b" style="display: none">
                This is box B
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showBoxA").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#box-a").toggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        var $el = $("#box-a");
        if ($el.is(":visible")) {
            $el.fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    width: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.boxes {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    width: 12rem;
}
```

What I want is something like:

```
        <div class="buttons-div">
            <div class="buttons" onClick="toggleViz(box-a)">A</div>
            <div class="buttons" onClick="toggleViz(box-b)">B</div>
        </div>

        <div id="boxes-div" style="z-index: 7">
            <div class="boxes" id="box-a" style="display: none">
                This is box A
            </div>
            <div class="boxes" id="box-b" style="display: none">
                This is box B
            </div>
        </div>
```

Where the JS would be something like:

```
function toggleViz(idname) {
    this.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(idname).toggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        var $el = $(idname);
        if ($el.is(":visible")) {
            $el.fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there something like this that could work? Thanks!